# Showing points of inflection of a certain quartic polynomial lie on the $x$-axis

Tags: calculus, polynomials

I am trying to find an elegant solution to this problem:

> Let $f(x)$ be a quartic polynomial with four real roots, $\alpha < \beta < \gamma < \delta$. The area enclosed by the curve $y=f(x)$ and the $x$-axis between $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is equal to that between $\gamma$ and $\delta$, and half that between $\beta$ and $\gamma$. Show that the points of inflection on $y=f(x)$ lie on the $x$-axis.

Any hints?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @integrand writing a general expression for f(x), twice-differentiating it to determine the x coordinates of the points of inflection, then substituting that into f(x) to obtain the y coordinates, then integrating f between the given roots to obtain two equations. I am now trying to show that the aforementioned y coordinates equal 0 using those equations

Comment: that is awfully messy though - I want to know if there is a simple & elegant proof.

Comment: You might be able to simplify the arithmetic by taking $f(x)=120 x(x-\beta)(x-\gamma)(x-1)$ but this won't lead to a different method